# Kotlin Upper Bound: What difference does `:Any` make to Kotlin's generic type inference?

Tags: android, generics, types, kotlin, type-inference

Following the `Kotlin for Android Developers` book, we come across extension function

```
fun <T:Any> SelectQueryBuilder.parseList(parser: (Map<String,Any?>) -> T):List<T> = parseList(object:MapRowParser<T>{
    override fun parseRow(columns: Map<String, Any?>): T = parser(columns)
})
```

And I'm not sure why the `:Any` is necessary.

If I write it as `fun <T> SelectQueryBuilder.parseList(...)`, Android Studio complains that

[image: error message]

whereas that error goes away when you add the `:Any` back.

Now, as far as I'm concerned, `T` should imply `T:Any`, though that is clearly not the case. Why is that? And what difference does it make?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Now, as far as I'm concerned, `T` should imply `T:Any`

`T` implies `T:Any?`, where `Any?` is the closest equivalent to Java's `Object`. With `T:Any` you specified a non-nullable type.

Answer (score 1):

The `:Any` defines an **upper bound** for your generic type argument. As you can read in the [Generics: Upper Bounds](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#upper-bounds) chapter of the Kotlin documentation, the default upper bound is `Any?`:

> The default upper bound (if none specified) is `Any?`

Thus, `<T>` is equivalent to `<T: Any?>`