# Why set collection to null is illegal in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

For example:

```
fun <K, V> setMap(map: MutableMap<K, V>, key: K) {
    // error:
    // Null can not be a value of a non-null type TypeVariable(V)
    map[key] = null
}
```

See this problem:
[What's the difference between T and T? in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63755329/whats-the-difference-between-t-and-t-in-kotlin)

It means:

```
<T> -> <T: Any?>
```

thus, above function actually should be:

```
<K, V> -> <K : Any?, V: Any?>
```

thus

```
// should be right: null belong to <V: Any?>
map[key] = null
```

Another example:

```
fun <T> testList(list: MutableList<T>) {
    val x = list[0]
    if (x == null) {
        println(x)
    } else {
        // error:
        // Null can not be a value of a non-null type T
        list[0] = null
    }
    
    // no error!
    testAny(null)
}

fun <T> testAny(any: T) {
    
}
```

Comment: No you're looking at it from the wrong side. `V: Any?` defines an upper bound to V that any Type it holds must be an implementation of `Any?`, that means it can not only be nullable type such as `String?` but can also be `String` which is subtype of of `Any` which is subtype of `Any?`.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu because I was thinking and found something wrong

Comment: If you just want to clear an entry, even on a map with non-nullable values, use `map.remove(key)`.

Answer (score 1):

`V: Any?` does not mean V must be `Int?` or `String?` etc, but also can be one of `Any`, `Int`, `String`, etc.

`Any?` is an upper bound to V, So any implementations it could be, so does not states "must be" nullable.

You should instead use:

```kotlin
// V: Any instead of plain V, will have the same effect as below
fun <K, V> setMap(map: MutableMap<K, V?>, key: K) {
    map[key] = null
}
```

***I'd recommend you to have a closer look at how generics work: https://proandroiddev.com/understanding-generics-and-variance-in-kotlin-714c14564c47 :^)***

#### Edit (on edited question):

[image: Kotlin Type system]

Kotlin type system is like this ^, that means `Int` is a subtype of `Int?`, to better demonstrate this, look at the following example:

```kotlin
val nonNull: Int = 5

// you can store `Int` type within variable of type `Int?`
val a: Int? = nonNull

// you can store `Int` type within variable of type `Any`
val b: Any = nonNull

// you can store `Int` type within variable of type `Any?`
val c: Any? = nonNull
```

That means `Int : Any : Any?` and `Int : Int? : Any?`. In both the way, you can see that `Int` is also a subtype of `Any?`

Now calling your function like this:

```kotlin
val listWithNulls: MutableList<Int?> = mutableListOf(2, 3, null, 5)
val listWithoutNulls: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf(2, 3, 4, 5)

testList(listWithNulls)  // T passed as Int?
testList(listWithNulls)  // T passed as Int <------ Here's the problem
```

See the above, example, in the `testList(listWithNulls)`, T is `Int` (it is an implementation of `Any?`) but is a non-nullable type in the type-system.

How will you be able to put `null` in `listWithNulls: MutableList<Int>`

#### Edit 2: To simplify even more:

```kotlin
val mutableListOfInts: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf(2, 3, 4, 5)

// Error: MutableList<Int> is not a subtype of MutableList<Any?>
val mutableListOfNullableInts: MutableList<Any?> = mutableListOfInts
```

`MutableList<Int>` is never a `MutableList<Any?>` or `MutableList<Int?>`, because MutableList is not covariant (you can add/retrieve elements). It is invariant, so there's no relation between those.

```kotlin
val listOfInts: List<Int> = ListOf(2, 3, 4, 5)

// Perfectly fine
val listOfNullableInts: List<Any?> = listOfInts
```

In this example, the `List<Int>` is a subtype of `List<Any?>` because you cannot modify it / push new elements into it. It is declared as `List<out E>` so is covariant and follows the same convention as you know.

In the same way:

```kotlin
fun <T> testList(list: MutableList<T>) {
    // Error: MutableList<T> is not a subtype of MutableList<Any?>
    val list2: MutableList<Any?> = list
}
```

It is not guaranteed `T` is nullable, so `MutableList<T>` can hold nulls or may not hold nulls.

Comment: @FredSuvn Think in this way: you can send `MutableMap<String, String>` and `MutableMap<String, String?>` because `String? : Any?` and `String : String? : Any?`, now back propagate this thing backwards.

Comment: you mean, `V` is one of `Any?` this is clearly, but `null` may not be one of `V`, so map refuse `null`?

Comment: @FredSuvn Yes, because `Any : Any?`, or say Non-Null types are subtypes of Nullable ones. I did not understood your question after "but".

Comment: I mean, map's value type is `V`, and `V` is subtype of `Any?`, and `null` is subtype of `Any?`, and there is no direct relationship between `V` and `null`, thus map refuses `null` because what's map required is only type `V`

Comment: `null` is of type [`Nothing?`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-nothing.html), an imaginary subtype of all the classes. I am recommending you to read the article above in the answer, it explains the [`contravariance`](https://proandroiddev.com/understanding-generics-and-variance-in-kotlin-714c14564c47#c4a4) clearly, i.e. in `in` type generics, relation is opposite, i.e. a `Int` is subtype of `Any`, but `Consumer<Any>` is a **subtype** of `Consumer<Int>`.

Comment: Similarly if you tryna push value to the Map, relation is contravariant, if you value from collection relation is covariant.

Comment: I have been read that link. Well, if this is about contravariance behavior, `null` is subtype of `V`, map should accepts it. And the IDEA should tips me: `Type missed` even if map refuses `null`, not shows `Null can not be a value of a non-null type TypeVariable(V)`

Comment: And, there is no limit no modifier on `<V>`, to make it `not null`

Comment: I add another example on my question end, see it, please ~

Comment: @FredSuvn in contravariance, `<V>` will be subtype of null (represented by type `<Nothing?>` in type-system).

Comment: @FredSuvn see the edited answer, it will explain you in detail.

Comment: Wow, that's the point, MutableCollection is `invariant`! Thus `V` is `V`, whatever `null` is sub or super type of `V`, thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in your error mesage, the compiler does not accept `null` value assignment, in case your type is a non-null type. In Kotlin, non-null types are aimed to eliminate `NullPointerException`s from your code.

You can read more about it [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html).

Depending on what is the type of your map, you need to handle `null` values accordingly:

```
fun <K, V> setMap(map: MutableMap<K, V>, key: K) {
    map[key] = 0;
}
```

Comment: `V` is not necessarily a Non-Null type, it can be Nullable or Non-Nullable as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50248546/kotlin-upper-bound-what-difference-does-any-make-to-kotlins-generic-type-in). Concern here is that if by any means `V` would be sent as non-nullable type as the function argument then how would you handle that, and so does the compiler complaints.

Comment: Right. Edited the answer.

Comment: @FredSuvn Yes, Non-Null types are sub types of Null types, this is why you can assign non-null values like `3` of type `Int` to variable of type `Int?`. So `<V: Any?>` can hold both non-null and nullable types, and so you are not permitted to set nulls to (if there was) non-null type.